# rails route not matching pdf format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have setup a route for access control to my uploads folder. The route catches all formats (.jpg, etc.) except pdf files.

```
match '/uploads/*path' => 'uploads#show'
```

Its the first route in routes.rb file.

Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

Check out 11.2 [RESTful Downloads](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) in the Rails Guides for more details, but you might need to add `Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf` to the `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` file

Comment: no, the mime type is already registred. seems like a browser caching problem.